# converting ascii into object

Tags: javascript

When a user lands on our site a cookie is created. I need to access this cookie and insert it into an object. However, the cookie is coming in this way:

```
%7B%22tpl%22%3A%22243%22%2C%22offer%22%3A%22596%22%2C%22userid%22%3A%227035%22%2C%22mediaid%22%3A%223066%22%2C%22r%22%3A%2222784176%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22LA%22%7D
```

How can I convert it to something more readable like:

```
{"key" : "value"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), which understands percent notation.